# Type Erasure for task scheduling mechanism

Tags: swift, type-erasure

I'm trying to build a light weight task scheduling system.  Basically I can wrap some async work in a `Task` and dispatch it with a `TaskRunner`.  Currently the runner is very simple just calling `start` on the `Task` and retaining it so that it isn't deallocated while it does work.  The task looks like this:

```
enum TaskNotification<T> {
    case start
    case cancel
    case complete(T)
    case progress(TaskProgress)
}

typealias TaskNotificationHandler<TaskResponseType> = (TaskNotification<TaskResponseType>) -> Void

protocol Task: AnyObject {

    associatedtype Response

    var onChange: TaskNotificationHandler<Response> { get set }

    func start()
    func cancel()
}
```

So I like the fact that I get the strong typing of the associatedType `Response`.  However, when it comes time to build the `TaskRunner` I get the classic `"contains Self or AssociatedType requirements"` compiler error so I use `T: Task` or I create a type-erased wrapper called `AnyTask`.

```
class TaskRunner {

    var currentTask: AnyTask<???>

    func run<T: Task>(task: T) {
        let boxed = AnyTask<???>(with: task)
        currentTask = task
        task.start()
    }
}
```

But even with the type-erasure (still not clear on what is and isn't being "erased") it still requires me to decide on a single concrete type for the generic parameter `<???>`.

In the end what I want is to be able to construct a concrete implementation of `Task` with the strong typing from the protocol's associated type, but allow the `TaskRunner` to manage arbitrary `Task`'s using just the functionality it cares about.  (e.g. it doesn't care about the strongly typed response)

I've looked over generics, type-erasure, and even using a class hierarchy but haven't found a decent solution.

Comment: I'm a little confused about `currentTask`. Do you really mean to throw away an in-progress task if another task starts? At what point should TaskRunner let go of its running task?

Comment: in this current state its just holding onto the one running task but in the future it might be a queue of them.  the type constraint issue is the same for a single element or a collection though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the goal is for `TaskRunner` to keep track of all running tasks until they emit `.complete` or `.cancel`. If that's the goal, then a basic block (`() -> Void`) is all the type-erasure you need.

```
class TaskRunner {
    // An increasing identifier just to keep track of things that aren't equatable
    var nextTaskId = 0

    var inProgressTasks: [Int: () -> Void] = [:]

    func run<T: Task>(task: T) {
        // Get an id
        let taskId = nextTaskId
        nextTaskId += 1

        // This allows you easily write a `TaskRunner.cancelAll()` method, so
        // it's useful. But it's real point is to retain `task` until it 
        // completes, while type-erasing it so it can be stored in inProgressTasks
        let cancel: () -> Void = {
            task.cancel()
        }

        // Extend the onChange handler to remove this task when it completes.
        // This intentionally retains self so the TaskRunner cannot go away
        // until all Tasks complete
        let oldChange = task.onChange
        task.onChange = { [self] notification in
            oldChange(notification)

            switch notification {
            case .complete, .cancel: self.inProgressTasks.removeValue(forKey: taskId)
            case .start, .progress: break
            }
        }

        // Retain the task via its canceller
        inProgressTasks[taskId] = cancel

        // Run it!
        task.start()
    }
}
```

Comment: is it that the  `cancel` closure is implicitly retaining `task`?  and the closure itself being the "type erasure"?

Comment: Yes, `cancel` retains `task`, and it'll be removed when the task completes (at `removeValue()`). And yes, the closure is type-erasing. It accepts an arbitrary type (T), and exposes only a `() -> Void`, "erasing" T.